# Expression.New(..) - but I already have an object

Tags: c#, expression-trees

Looking at expression trees in C# and was reading [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402755(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
// Add the following directive to your file:
// using System.Linq.Expressions;  
public class SampleClass
{
    public int AddIntegers(int arg1, int arg2)
    {
        return arg1 + arg2;
    }
}

static public void TestCall()
{
    // This expression represents a call to an instance method that has two arguments.
    // The first argument is an expression that creates a new object of the specified type.
    Expression callExpr = Expression.Call(
        Expression.New(typeof(SampleClass)),
        typeof(SampleClass).GetMethod("AddIntegers", new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }),
        Expression.Constant(1),
        Expression.Constant(2)
        );

    // Print out the expression.
    Console.WriteLine(callExpr.ToString());

    // The following statement first creates an expression tree,
    // then compiles it, and then executes it.
    Console.WriteLine(Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(callExpr).Compile()());

    // This code example produces the following output:
    //
    // new SampleClass().AddIntegers(1, 2)
    // 3
}
```

I want to do something almost identical to this, except I don't want to create a new instance of `SampleClass` - I already have an instance, I just want to invoke a method on it.

The code essentially does this:

```
new SampleClass().AddIntegers(1, 2)
```

...using expression trees; however, I want to do this:

```
sampleClassInstance.AddIntegers(1, 2)
```

Is this something I can do, or should I just stick with reflection for this?

Comment: Sure you can, just replace the expression to create an instance with an expression to use an existing instance.  What problems are you having doing that?  Also please include all of the relevant details *in the question itself*.  People shouldn't have to read the link to understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Servy. What is the syntax to do that?

Comment: It's the same as the syntax for creating an expression based on any other value that you have, which is showcased right in the article that you referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public int AddIntegers(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}

var sampleClass = new SampleClass();
Expression callExpr = Expression.Call(
    Expression.Constant(sampleClass),
    typeof(SampleClass).GetMethod("AddIntegers", new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }),
    Expression.Constant(1),
    Expression.Constant(2)
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for.